# Djnago signals how to delete old object if new object created?

Tags: django

I am using django signals for showing notifications. If any post created in my blog then it will notify the blog author and pending for admin approval see the picture:
[image]

if admin approve the blog post then author will get another new notification. I want to delete old  pending notification of **post1** if new notification created for **post1**. see the picture:
[image]

here is my signals code for create notification:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
      .....my fields
      #signals code
     def blog_notify(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
          blog = instance
          blog_title = blog.title
          sender = blog.author

          if sender == blog.author and blog.is_published == "published":
             notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, user=sender,text_preview = blog_title[:250], notification_type="post approved")
             notify.save()

          if sender == blog.author and blog.is_published == "pending":
             notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, user=sender,text_preview = blog_title[:250], notification_type="pending post")
             notify.save()
post_save.connect(Blog.blog_notify, sender=Blog)
```

**#UPDATE QUESTION**
Ajay saini tried to give solution what I wanted but I found an problems in Ajay saini solution. If any object don't have any previous notification for delete then it will raise error. His solution working for existing notification or old object.

Comment: Why not update the notification with the new status? I believe you could find the notification using the blog as key (Notification.objects.get(blog=blog)

Comment: angardi  can you plase show me an expample? how to update notification in models for existing object? will it be notify.update()???

Answer (score 1):

Delete pending notification once published.

```
 def blog_notify(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
          blog = instance
          blog_title = blog.title
          sender = blog.author

          if sender == blog.author and blog.is_published == "published":
             notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, user=sender,text_preview = blog_title[:250], notification_type="post approved")
             notify.save()

             # Delete all pending notifications for specific blog 
             Notifications.objects.filter(blog=blog, sender=sender, user=sender, notification_type="pending post").delete()

          if sender == blog.author and blog.is_published == "pending":
             notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, user=sender,text_preview = blog_title[:250], notification_type="pending post")
             notify.save()
```

Comment: This also works. My suggestion was to update the status of the same notification in case you had links pointing to them.

Comment: Yes @angardi your approach makes more sense. but I wrote delete in case if OP wants to know the logic to delete the object.

Comment: Ajay saini Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't want to delete any object. I just want to  replace post1 pending notification with post1 approved notification. I want to keep track my old notification in my database. if new object of post1 created then old object of post1 will be not be show in template. Your solution look like what I wanted but it's deleting the object which I don't want

Comment: Then you can have a flag in notification model and change it once the post is approved. use that flag to show/hide notifications to end-user.

Comment: Ajay saini what is  flag? any like or documentation???

Comment: I meant just a boolean field

Comment: Ajay saini  I am getting an error `Notifications object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.` because it's new object and didn't have any previous object for delete

Comment: Ajay saini  your solution working for existing object but what happen if new object created and don't have any previous notification for delete ???